# Method of Exhaustion: intuition behind inequalities

Tags: calculus, geometry, approximation, area

In Apostol's *One-Variable Calculus, with an Introduction to Linear Algebra*, when discussing the method of exhaustion for solving for the area under a curve (specifically $x^2$), Apostol sets up the following inequality:

$$1^2 + 2^2 + ... + (n-1)^2 < \frac{n^3}{3} < 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2$$

He goes on to state that it is valid for every integer $n\geq1$ and that **they can be deduced easily as consequences of the following formulas**:

1.3) $$1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 = \frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}$$

1.4) $$1^2 + 2^2 + ... + (n-1)^2 = \frac{n^3}{3} - \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}$$

I'm a bit confused at how he is able to deduce this from just 1.3 and 1.4 alone.  Is it because since $n\geq1$, $\frac{n^2}{2}$ is certainly greater than $\frac{n}{6}$ and so we know 1.3 is greater than $\frac{n^3}{3}$ and vice versa for 1.4?  Is there a more concrete explanation for how 1.3 and 1.4 setup the inequality?  An induction proof is shared later on but I'm specifically interested in the intuition of the above!

Comment: 1.3) $\dfrac {n^2}{2} + \dfrac n 6 < \dfrac {n^2}{2}+\dfrac {n^2}{2}= n^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHS of **1.3)** is greater than $n^3/3$, this is really obvious because the RHS is just $n^3/3$ plus something that is positive. That something is $(n^2/2 + n/6)$.

RHS of **1.4)** is smaller than $n^3/3$. OK, this is not so obvious but still quite obvious. That's true because $$(-n^2/2 + n/6) \lt 0$$ for every natural number $n$. You can prove this easily yourself e.g. by induction. Or, if you don't want to use induction (to prove this inequality), you can just notice that it is equivalent to $$n(3n-1)\gt0$$ which of course is true for every natural number $n$.

**Note:** RHS means *"right hand side"*

These two observations prove that the sum in **1.3)** is greater than $n^3/3$ while the sum in **1.4)** is smaller than $n^3/3$, and that is exactly what you want to prove here.